# How to get information back from tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i am using oracle sqlplus on the sample HR database tables.

I have 2 tables, employees and jobs in which i have job_id in both of them.

I want to be able to enter the input of the job_ID and then it displays the first_name, last_name (which is inside employees table)

I am new to sql and learning. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you want to query data out of an SQL Database, you need the SELECT Statement. In your case, that would be:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Employees WHERE job_ID=:job_ID;
```

`SELECT` ... Keyword of "SELECT" Statements

`firstname, lastname` ... Columns you want the query to return

`FROM Employees` ... Keyword + Tablename you want to query on

`WHERE job_ID=:job_ID` ... Condition which will be used to select specific rows

`:job_ID` ... Your input of which job_ID you want to get

Your searched Query was the userinput mixed with the Jobs:

`SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Employees JOIN Jobs ON Employees.job_ID=Jobs.job_ID WHERE Jobs.min_salary=&min_salary AND Jobs.max_salary=&max_salary;`

`JOIN` Combines the rows of each table to one bigger table, there are many different types of them, this is just the basic one

`ON` Gives the JOIN the parameter to check whether this column is the same in two rows of each table. If yes, they will be merged

Comment: So this is what im trying to do, I have 2 tables. One employee and jobs. Employee consists of first_name, last_name and other things, Jobs consists of min_salary, max_salary, job_id, and job_title. I want to be asked to enter a min and max salary from where it can choose rows to work with, then it can take the job_ID from jobs and look at the employee table that also has job_id. Then i want it to display all the information from the rows of employees of the job_id's it got by me specifying a min and max salary

Comment: Following this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/parameter.php) you can easily put `&job_ID` instead of `:job_ID`

Comment: Yes i have looked at that link. I am having trouble getting the info from min and max salary to connect with the job_id on jobs which i want to use on the employees job_id and display everything in employees

Comment: So you need something like this?: `SELECT firstname, lastname, ... FROM Employee JOIN Jobs ON Employee.job_ID=Jobs.job_ID WHERE Jobs.min_salary=&min_salary AND Jobs.max_salary=&max_salary;`
Or do you want a salary which is in the range of the min-max salary? If yes, I will redisgn my answer of course :)

Comment: Basically, i want to Create query in which when you enter the min and max salary, it pulls up the all the employee info. I entered your code and it says table or view does not exist, i think with the code you provided i could mess it with it until i get it to how i want :) but im not sure why its showing table or view doesnt exist?

Comment: After the SELECT, i put "..." to visualize that you can put more columns here :) Tell me if that works: `SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Employee JOIN Jobs ON Employee.job_ID=Jobs.job_ID WHERE Jobs.min_salary=&min_salary AND Jobs.max_salary=&max_salary;`

Comment: Yes, i had removed the .. to only get first and last name, but still getting same error. Table does not view or exist. And my table has first_name and last_name which i fixed.

Comment: Yeah can't edit the comment, but i think its Employees instead of Employee as well: `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Employees JOIN Jobs ON Employees.job_ID=Jobs.job_ID WHERE Jobs.min_salary=&min_salary AND Jobs.max_salary=&max_salary;`

Comment: I feel very stupid xD. Thank you SO much. It works:) now i can add more informatioon :)

Comment: You have to start somewhere, of course :) I updated my answer according to this solution :)